# Xamarin.Forms Tabbed Pages and Logging Out

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am experiencing an odd behaviour using Xamarin.Forms which I can't work out.

The basic flow of the app is that the landing page is a Login form. When logging in, this takes you to a tabbed page. When I use the Logout function it returns you back to login page, however the tabs seem to remain in place.

**Login.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TechsportiseApp.Login">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                    Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                    WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Orientation="Vertical"
                     Spacing="15">
            <Label Text="Email" />
            <Entry x:Name="email" Text="123@test.com" />
            <Label Text="Password"  />
            <Entry x:Name="password" Text="xxxxxx" IsPassword="true"/>
            <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Login" Clicked="OnLogin"/>
            <Button x:Name="registerButton" Text="Register Account" Clicked="OnRegister"/>
            <Button x:Name="clearButton" Text="Reset" Clicked="OnClear"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

If I get a success code from the API for the login, This section moves them to the MainPage.

**Login.xaml.cs**

```
//Valid response
                if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                {
                    Application.Current.Properties["Token"] = tokenobject.access_token;
                    string token = Application.Current.Properties["Token"].ToString();
                    Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new MainPage (), this);
                    await Navigation.PopAsync();

                }
```

**MainPage.xaml** looks like this and is a tabbed Navigation page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TechsportiseApp.MainUI" 
    x:Class="TechsportiseApp.MainUI.MainPage">

    <local:Races />
    <local:Timer />
    <local:Scanning />
    <NavigationPage Title="Settings">
        <x:Arguments>
            <local:Settings />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Each of the pages there are all Valid. The Settings page has a Logout button.

**Settings.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="TechsportiseApp.MainUI.Settings"
             Title="Settings">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Settings will go here" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <Button x:Name="logoutButton" Text="Logout" Clicked="OnLogout" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

With the Logout button in **Settings.xaml.cs** doing this

```
async void OnLogout(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.Properties["Token"] = "";
    Navigation.InsertPageBefore (new Login(), this);
    await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

But the end result is that I have the Login screen... with the Tab bar at the bottom

[image]

What have I done wrong? I'd like it so when I logout the tabs aren't visible.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Your NavigationPage is inside of your TabbedPage, so anything you do with Navigation will remain inside the TabbedPage.  You should replace your app's MainPage instead.

Comment: Try moving you TabbedPage inside NavigationPage. On logout, navigate to the Login page.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the new MainPage did the job. On Login and Logout I set the new MainPage for the app using

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
```

Instead of the PopAsync/PushAsync.